# C# Method Syntax to Query Syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I am pretty new to LINQ in C#. How can I rewrite the following using query syntax?

```
var jobs =
          context.Job
            .Include(j => j.PlannedJobStopDetails
              .Select(jsd => jsd.PlannedTravelStop)
            )
            .Where(
              j => j.DateUpdated >= dateFrom && j.DateUpdated <= dateTo &&
                   j.PlannedJobStopDetails.Any(
                     jsd => jsd.DateUpdated >= dateFrom && jsd.DateUpdated <= dateTo
                         && jsd.PlannedTravelStop.PlannedTravelStopStatus == status
                     )
            );
```

I am using Entity Framework and I am trying to run the query in LINQPad

Comment: For some of this, you can't. Why do you want to?

Comment: Something like `from j in context.Job.Include(...) where ... select j`? What have you tried?

Comment: @Rawling I want to run the query in LINQPad

Comment: @MunasheTsododo you can run the query in linqpad as is. Just do `jobs.Dump();` after you have Language to "C# Statement(s)"

Answer (score 1):

Set language to C# Statements and then use jobs.Dump(); to get the results ?

```
var jobs =
      context.Job
        .Include(j => j.PlannedJobStopDetails
          .Select(jsd => jsd.PlannedTravelStop)
        )
        .Where(
          j => j.DateUpdated >= dateFrom && j.DateUpdated <= dateTo &&
               j.PlannedJobStopDetails.Any(
                 jsd => jsd.DateUpdated >= dateFrom && jsd.DateUpdated <= dateTo
                     && jsd.PlannedTravelStop.PlannedTravelStopStatus == status
                 )
        );
jobs.Dump(); // execute the query in linqpad and dump results.
```

**Additional information added**

All the code you write in LinqPad will get contained within a class called UserQuery. Also all tables/views available from the connection you select will be available in this generated UserQuery class.

Using `context.` is not really needed. But because you used copy paste from your actual c# application you could use the following trick to just run a pasted query.

You add the following code before your query in linqpad:

```
var context = this;
```

An alternative to your query would be to return the language option in LinqPad to *C# expression* and just write the query without the `context` and the `.Dump();` at the end. Like this...

```
Job
.Include(
    j => j.PlannedJobStopDetails.Select(jsd => jsd.PlannedTravelStop)
)
.Where(
    j => j.DateUpdated >= dateFrom && j.DateUpdated <= dateTo &&
        j.PlannedJobStopDetails.Any(
            jsd => jsd.DateUpdated >= dateFrom && jsd.DateUpdated <= dateTo
                && jsd.PlannedTravelStop.PlannedTravelStopStatus == status
        )
)
```

Comment: It gives an error "The name 'context' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Added additional information for you regarding LinqPad.